# Работа с EXIF в iOS-приложениях

Tags: ios, exif

Всем привет.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно работать с EXIFом фотографий на iOS? Достаточно будет идеи или направления, указанное ссылкой) Хочется читать и модифицировать весь доступный EXIF, в том числе, расширенный.

Спасибо.

Comment: Правь как бинарник =)
И ссылки я что-то не вижу...

Comment: Поподробней, пожалуйста) Я пока новичок в iOS development)

Answer (score 1):

Я на самом деле не знаю, может быть есть и более удобный способ. 
В C++ можно через iostream например (подключаешь к своему .mm файлу обычный .cpp), можно и через какао классы файл править, кому что удобно. Надо только знать структуру файла.